# Can't "open with" certain programs in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

For example:

1. Right-click .pdf file
2. Click "Open with..."
3. "Choose default program"  (Reader is currently highlighted)
4. Click **Browse** button
5. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe`, press **Open**

Nothing happens.  Inkscape doesn't appear in the **Recommended Programs** or **Other Programs** lists, and the highlighted program is still Reader.  It's impossible to select Inkscape.  I've had this working in the past, but now I can't select it.

I've seen this in the past with other programs.  Sometimes I can set a program as the default (or as a non-default option that shows up in "Open with" sub-menu), other times I can't.  Why?

Comment: I suggest you restore the default file extension for the `.pdf` file extension.  I assume  Inkscape can open .pdf files if you manually open them from within Inkscape?

Comment: Yes, Inkscape can open PDF files.  I don't want it to be the default, it just want it to show up in the Open With submenu, but I can't do either of these.  It doesn't show up in the list even after selecting it from the list.